# How to add a if sort of condition in protobuf?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf definition like below,

```
message SearchRequest {
    string my_id = 1;

    enum MyStrategy {
            MY_TEST1 = 1;
            MY_TEST2 = 2;
    }
    MyStrategy my_strategy = 2;
}
```

Now I want to add an option like if MY_TEST2 is selected,  then client is asked to select again from another set of options, if MY_TEST1 is selected no options will be provided.

Comment: "Now I want to add an option like if MY_TEST2 is selected, then add one more enum." - I genuinely can't parse that sentence. Please could you rephrase, perhaps showing the sort of payloads you have in mind (with and without the "one more enum"). The DSL here is merely expressing the shape of a potential payload. It has no logic as such, but if you rephrase we might be able to offer guidance. It sounds like you might want an optional field somewhere? But since you appear to be using proto3, all fields are optional...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual act of prompting for values is a UI thing completely unrelated to protobuf; protobuf just describes data exchange, so I'm guessing (although please correct me) that what you're actually trying to say is:

> As part of a search, the user needs to choose a "strategy"; each strategy has different fields that need to be provided; how can I describe the fields needed for each strategy, and encode the selection of the strategy?

If so, it sounds like what you're actually trying to describe is a `oneof`, i.e.

```proto
syntax="proto3";
message SearchRequest {
    string my_id = 1;
    oneof strategy {
        SearchOptionsFoo foo = 2;
        SearchOptionsBar bar = 3;
    }
}
message SearchOptionsFoo {
    // fields here ...
}
message SearchOptionsBar {
    // fields here ...
}
```